# Populate selected candidates to terminal after fuzzy search with fzf via keybinding?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, zsh

With [this plugin](https://github.com/krickelkrakel/fzf-apt/blob/master/fzf-apt) we can fuzzy search through candidates of apt packages.

the output of running it as below:

```
# apt zzuf zziplib-bin zytrax
```

The code in the link (I put  `if [[ "${BASH_<...> fi` to a function `my-fuzzy-test`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
function insert_stdin {
    # if this wouldn't be an external script
    # we could use 'print -z' in zsh to edit the line buffer
    stty -echo
    perl -e 'ioctl(STDIN, 0x5412, $_) for split "", join " ", @ARGV;' \
        "$@"
}
function my-fuzzy-test() {
if [[ "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" == "${0}" ]]; then
    packages="$(apt list --verbose 2>/dev/null | \
        # remove "Listing..."
        tail --lines +2 | \
        # place the description on the same line
        # separate the description and the other information
        # with a ^
        sd $'\n {2}([^ ])' $'^$1' | \
        # place the package information and the package description
        # in a table with two columns
        column -t -s^ | \
        # select packages with fzf
        fzf --multi | \
        # remove everything except the package name
        cut --delimiter '/' --fields 1 | \
        # escape selected packages (to avoid unwanted code execution)
        # and remove line breaks
        xargs --max-args 1 --no-run-if-empty printf "%q ")"

    if [[ -n "${packages}" ]]; then
        insert_stdin "# apt ${@}" "${packages}"
    fi
fi
}
```

I put above code in `~/.zshrc` and map `my-fuzzy-test` to a keybinding:

```
zle -N my-fuzzy-test
bindkey "^[k" my-fuzzy-test
```

as press `alt-k` to trigger `my-fuzzy-test` function, it showed nothing when press `alt-k`.
If I remove line `if [[ "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" == "${0}" ]]; then` and `fi` at the end, then it can trigger the function but it can't display expected output as above and echoes error `stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device`

I know we can populate candidates into terminal's prompt as in [this code](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/f81feb1e69e5cb75797d50817752ddfe4933cd68/shell/key-bindings.zsh#L99) as below:

```
# CTRL-R - Paste the selected command from history into the command line
fzf-history-widget() {
  local selected num
  setopt localoptions noglobsubst noposixbuiltins pipefail no_aliases 2> /dev/null
  selected=( $(fc -rl 1 | perl -ne 'print if !$seen{(/^\s*[0-9]+\s+(.*)/, $1)}++' |
    FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS="--height ${FZF_TMUX_HEIGHT:-40%} $FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS -n2..,.. --tiebreak=index --bind=ctrl-r:toggle-sort $FZF_CTRL_R_OPTS --query=${(qqq)LBUFFER} +m" $(__fzfcmd)) )
  local ret=$?
  if [ -n "$selected" ]; then
    num=$selected[1]
    if [ -n "$num" ]; then
      zle vi-fetch-history -n $num
    fi
  fi
  zle reset-prompt
  return $ret
}
zle     -N   fzf-history-widget
bindkey '^R' fzf-history-widget
```

So how can I correctly populate candidate to terminal's prompt with `my-fuzzy-test`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Ctrl-R widget uses `zle vi-fetch-history` to insert history matches, which is not applicable to what you're doing here.

What you need to do is insert the matches you've generated into the editing buffer, as is done by another widget in the same code over here: https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/shell/key-bindings.zsh#L62

That widget inserts the matches `echo`ed by the function `__fsel` into the right side of the left part of the buffer (meaning, it inserts them into the current position of the cursor and then, afterwards, the cursor will end up to the right of what's inserted):

```bsh
LBUFFER="${LBUFFER}$(__fsel)"
```

Comment: So if `LBUFFER` has `a` and `__fsel` echoes `b` then after assign `LBUFFER` is `ab` and cursor is at end of `b` as like `ab|` <-- `|` is position of cursor.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.